# Can't store the result of pie() function R

Tags: r, variables, charts

I have a problem trying to store the result of my pie() function in a variable, it appears that it sets it to NULL whereas the plot is displayed, I don't understand why.
I want to store it in order to write it as an HTML file after.

Here is my code:

```
for(i in seq(1,13)){
  values <- c(stat_pcs_region[ i,"pop_agriculteurs"], stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_commercant"], stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_cadres"],
                                stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_profIntermediaire"], stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_employes"], stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_ouvriers"],
                                stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_retraites"], stat_pcs_region[i,"pop_chomage"])
  labels <- c("Agriculteurs", "Commercants, artisans et chef d entreprise", "Cadres", "Professions intermediares",
                                "Employes", "Ouvriers", "Retraites", "Chomeurs")
  percentage <-  round(values/sum(values)*100)
  labels <- paste(percentage, "% de", labels)
  p <- pie(values, labels, col = rainbow(9))
  saveWidget(p, file = paste("C:/Users/henri/Downloads/Rapports_appli_geo/Pie_charts_regions/piechartPCS_reg", i, ".html", sep = ""))
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: if you look at e.g. `body(pie)` you'll see that this is not straight-forward, as `pie` produces the pie-chart step-wise and actually returns `NULL`

Comment: The point is that I need to store it, I was using plotly but the result was very heavy and I don't need so much complexity...

Comment: and how about using `ggplot2` with `coord_polar`? http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_polar.html